# Having trouble with the print output for my Two Dimensional Arrays program

Tags: java

I'm attempting to make a program that takes a Two Dimensional Array from an input text file so I've modified it as such.  I think it looks alright, I've been trying different things, the only problem I'm encountering so far is the main method at the bottom and getting the print functions to work for each of the methods.  I'm doing this in Eclipse by the way.  For some reason using the list is giving me issues, the program was working when I had an array set in the main method itself, but I've been trying to modify it so that it takes a file.  I want to provide the ability to have the user enter a file name on the command line at stratup and if no command line argument is provided, then prompt the user for a filename.  So I think I'm on the right track but not sure.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TwoDimArray
{
    private static int[][] twodim;
    public TwoDimArray() {
        loadArray();
    }
    
    
    //main function
    
    public static int getTotal(int [][]numbers)
    {
        int tot=0;
        for(int row=0;row<numbers.length;row++)
            for(int col=0;col<numbers[row].length;col++)
                tot+=numbers[row][col];
        return tot;
    }
    
    public static double getAverage(int [][]numbers)
    {
        double avg;
        avg= (double)(getTotal(numbers)/(12));
        return avg;
    }
    public static int getRowTotal(int [][]numbers, int index)
    {
        int tot=0;
        for(int col=0;col<4;col++)
            tot+=numbers[index][col];
        return tot;
    }
    public static int getColumnTotal (int [][]numbers, int index)
    {
        int tot=0;
                for(int row=0;row<numbers.length;row++)
                    tot+=numbers[row][index];
        
        return tot;
    }
    
    public static int getHighest(int [][]numbers,int row)
    {
        int high=numbers[row][0];
        for(int i=1;i<numbers[row].length;i++)
            if(numbers[row][i]>high)
                high=numbers[row][i];
        return high;
    
    }
    public static int getLowest(int [][]numbers,int row)
    {
        int low=numbers[row][0];
        for(int i=1;i<numbers[row].length;i++) 
        
            if(numbers[row][i]<low)
                low=numbers[row][i];
        return low;
    }
    
    
    public void loadArray() {
        String fileName = "";
        
        try {
            fileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an input file name: ");
            
            if (fileName == null)
                throw new NullPointerException("Please do not press cancel!");
            
            Scanner infile = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
            
            if (!infile.hasNextLine()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The input file " + fileName + " is empty!");
                System.exit(1);
            }else {
                infile.reset();
                
                String strRows = infile.next();
                String strCols = infile.next();
                
                int rows = Integer.parseInt(strRows);
                int cols = Integer.parseInt(strCols);
                
                twodim = new int[rows][cols];
                
                for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                    String data = infile.next();
                    twodim[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(data);
                    
                }
            }
            infile.close();
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, npe.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "cannot convert input to integer");
        System.exit(1);
    }catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "The input file " + fileName + " doesn't exist!");
        System.exit(1);
    }
        
    }
        

    

    public static void main (String []arg)
        {
            //private int[][] twodim;
            //int [][]list= {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}};
            //Function call and display data returned
        
        TwoDimArray tda = new TwoDimArray();
        
            System.out.println("Total:"+getTotal(list));
            System.out.println("Average:"+getAverage(list));
            System.out.println("Row 2 value:"+getRowTotal(list,2));
            System.out.println("Column 3 Total :"+getColumnTotal(list,3));
            System.out.println("Highest value in row 1 is :"+getHighest(list,1));
            System.out.println("Lowest value in row 2 is :"+getLowest(list,2));
            
            //Exit program
            System.exit(0);
        }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please read: [How to create a **Minimal**, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: My question is how to get this to print output

Answer (score 0):

This method prints a 2 dim array:

```
public void printMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
    for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < matrix[0].length; col++) {
            System.out.print(matrix[row][col] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```